# send multiple requests simultaneously using CONCURRENCY_REQUEST using Scrapy

Tags: python, concurrency, scrapy, request, simultaneous

Please,
How to configure exactly the CONCURRENCY_REQUEST, CONCURRENCY_REQUEST_PER_DOMAIN for to send multiple requests simultaneously ?
My DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5 and CONCURRENCY_REQUEST_PER_IP = 1

When I set CONCURRENCY_REQUEST = 4 there is no difference in time and I don't understand

Comment: When you use `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP ` setting (on your case - 1) - scrapy will ignore `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`  and `CONCURRET_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` settings.

Comment: Ah okay, well I have a list of ip, how to configure for there are one request for each ip but simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped name of settings 
 there is no `CONCURRENCY_REQUEST` , `CONCURRENCY_REQUEST_PER_DOMAIN` and  `CONCURRENCY_REQUEST_PER_IP`  settings in scrapy.

You need to use `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` , `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` 
[`CONCURRENT_` not
`CONCURRENCY_`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests)

Comment: Sorry i want to ask with CONCURRENT_, I don't understand how to configure this